# How to enter line break after every xml closing tag by using javascript replace function?

Tags: javascript, xml, replace, format, str-replace

I am using the following  javascript replace function while formatting my xml code.

```
xml = xmll.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g, '');
```

But it is not creating line break even i used the following function too to create new line.

```
xml = xmll.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g, '\n');
```

Still it did nt create line break or new line after closing tags of xml. Can anybody know what should be the possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
xml = xmll.replace(/(<\/?.*?>)/g, '$1\n');
```

Comment: Respected sir, it is really working. but sir, i was eliminating <0> tag but now <0> tag is again showing. as i dnt want to display node indexes such as <0> <1> and so on.

Comment: Then try this one. xml = xmll.replace(/(<\/?.*?>)/g, '\n');

Comment: Thanks sir, its also working but now it eliminating all of the closing and ending tags. but i want to eliminate or replace only <0> </0> <1> </1> tags and so on all the indexes. but not my xml tags such as <body></body>.

Comment: and can you explain this expression so i may able to produce my own according to my requirement. would be thankful.

Comment: Actullay it's same as `[0-9]{1,}` but it check for any characters not only `digits`.  if my regex is working then your regex should also work. there is no difference .

Comment: sir thanks alot for answering with best. stay blessed.